# How Do I change the Color of the Register/Login TextButton in FlutterFireUI Screen?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebaseui

I'm trying to change the color of the Register button in the "don't have an account? Register" widget in the FlutterFireUI loginScreen page

[the button I want to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hi2qt.png)

I thought it was a TextButton at first like the forget password button so I added the following code inside the ThemeData widget for the MaterialApp

```
textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
     style: TextButton.styleFrom(
     foregroundColor:  Color(0xFF6F73D2),// Text Color
    ),
 ),
```

but it turned out to be a RichText widget instead

I looked online for hours but I can't find how to change its color

Comment: I'm not familiar with FlutterFireUI but if it is a `RichText`, you should be able to provide a `TextSpan` and then a `style` to it to change its color.

Comment: FlutterFireUI automatically builds the entire login screen so in order to change the style of a certain widget you need to change the themeData from the material app.
I don't think you can add Textspan to that

Answer (score 0):

```
RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
            text: "Don't have an account? ",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            children: [
              TextSpan(
                text: ' Register',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Color(0xFF6F73D2),
                ),
                recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                  ..onTap = () {
                    //BUTTON ACTION
                  },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```